# check all extensions in DB

Tags: php

I have a database with a column named "document_name". In that column are thousands of rows with document names, like:

```
kfhidfs.doc
kjfdjdf.png
dsdiusd.exe
etc.
etc.
```

I want to know which extensions my users uploaded in the past.
So, I select all rows:

```
$sql = "SELECT document_name FROM docs";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($fetch_doc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

And I know that I can split the name and the extension using EXPLODE, like:

```
// Example 1
$doc = $fetch_doc['document_name'];
$piece = explode(".", $doc);
echo $piece[0]; // document name
echo $piece[1]; // extension
```

But I only want to see each extension max. 1 time, as I want know which extensions are in the DB, I don't want to know how many.

But how can I arrange that?

Answer (score 2):

Add them to an array, only if they're not already there:

```
$extensions = array();
while($fetch_doc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $doc = $fetch_doc['document_name'];
    $piece = explode(".", $doc);
    $extension = $piece[1];
    if (!in_array($extension, $extensions) {
        $extensions[] = $extension;
    }
}
// Here $extensions is an array of the different extensions, each present only once
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL to achieve that, what is most likely more powerful than PHP.

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(document_name,',',-2),',',1) AS extension 
FROM docs
GROUP BY extension
```

This assumes there is only one `.`before the file extension

You can use that query with PHP like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(document_name,',',-2),',',1) AS extension FROM docs GROUP BY extension";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($extension = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  var_dump($extension);
}
```

BTW:

> The original mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: When i use this one, i get a list that only says: ARRAY ARRAY ARRAY

What do i do wrong?

Comment: @user3303790 Nothing, my example has mistake in it. Replace `echo $extension;` with `var_dump($extension);` then you'll see the array content. (Becasue you can't echo an array)

Comment: @user3303790 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If you accept answers people will be more motivated to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$extensions = array();
while($fetch_doc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $doc = $fetch_doc['document_name'];
  $piece = explode(".", $doc);
  $extensions[$piece[1]] = true;
}

foreach($extensions AS $key=>$value) {
  echo $key . "<br />";
}
```

In this way you add every extension to an array (a key can only exist once, so you will automatically have each extension only once). You will echo the contents of the array thereafter.